# How to set custom Image on NavigationItem of Felgo/QML

Tags: qt, qml, felgo

I am using qt, and my navigation item need to set custom image from the device, How to set Image  on NavigationItem?

```
  App {  
      Navigation {
        NavigationItem {
          title: "Main"
           //I need set Image on this item, kindly help me. I know there is icon, but I dont know how to set custom image.
          //Image{ "  icon.source: "https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/shutterstock_1006988770.png""
          //      anchors.left:parent.left       
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Navigation is not part of the QML standard, are you using a library like Felgo?

Comment: yes. felgo I am using

Comment: have you tried:  `icon.source: "file:///C:/Users/Nourin/Pictures/cnt.png"`?

Comment: I got error "file:WebEditor/qml/WebScriptMain.qml:8: Invalid grouped property access"

Comment: Now I have uodated url source from http. still error is same.

Comment: It looks like you have to use `IconType` constant, or use the `iconComponent` property to place you commented `Image`, like: `iconComponent: Image { source: "http..." }`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly -- you want to set navigation item image to be something more than one of the [`IconType`](https://felgo.com/doc/felgo-icontype/) constants. To make it possible you need to declare your own component and set as [`iconComponent`](https://felgo.com/doc/felgo-navigationitem/#iconComponent-prop). Also, keep in mind that you are not limited to use only images there -- you can use any kind of UI element (for reference, see example in official documentation).

Here is an example implementation you can try yourself:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import Felgo 3.0

App {
  // Here CustomNavigationImage is inline declaration of a component.
  // If your Qt is lower then 5.15, you can declare this component in a separate file.
  component CustomNavigationImage: AppImage {
    anchors.fill: parent
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
  }

  Navigation {
    navigationMode: navigationModeTabsAndDrawer

    NavigationItem {
      title: "Custom Page"
      iconComponent: CustomNavigationImage {
        defaultSource: "https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/shutterstock_1006988770.png"
      }
      NavigationStack {
        Page { title: "Custom page" }
      }
    }

    NavigationItem {
      title: "StackOveflow image"
      iconComponent: CustomNavigationImage {
        defaultSource: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png"
      }
      NavigationStack {
        Page { title: "StackOveflow image" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```